# Spacing issue within the item in enumerate environment

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize, line-spacing

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\item This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\item This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\end{enumerate}
```

The outcome is shown in the image. I am writing a document, and in it I require a uniform spacing of 1.5 pt. But in the enumerate environment, between items I am able to get the spacing of 1.5 pt, but within the item itself I am not able to get the required spacing.
[image]

Comment: it is better to make your example complete and not just a fragment.

Comment: Please start your posted code with `\documentclass`, end it with `\enddocument` and provide everything else needed to make it compile. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

- You not provide any information about your document (used document class, pages layout, how the distance 1.5 pt between lines are setup. etc.), below is possible solution for your problem ...
- by remove all extra vertical spaces by use `enumitem` packages, you can obtain:

[image]

As you can see all vertical distances are now the same ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}      % <---

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]   % <---
\item This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the first sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\item This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the second sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\item This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything. This is the third sentence and it doesn't mean anything.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can set `nosep` option globally for all king of used lists by inserting `\setlist{nosep}`  after loading `enumitem` package in document preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zarko. But by using `nosep`, there is now no spacing between the items. However, in my case, the spacing between the items was not an issue. The only problem was the spacing within the item. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @AS, text in list items has the same baseline size as in main text. Please, make first your question more complete and clear, that we does not need to guess what you after.